# Running "print" raises "TypeError" in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `python version 3.4.3`. I need to print a `string`. So I tried:

```
print ("Hello world")
```

I got below error

> TypeError : 'str' object is not callable

I tried below way,

```
str  ("Hello world")
```

and got below output

> 'Hello World'

Is it possible to get the output as below?

> Hello World

i.e without the quotes.

Comment: `>>> print("Hello World")` gives me
`Hello World`. Where are you using Python?

Comment: You're using `print` as a variable name somewhere.

Comment: The only way I see to have this error is if you have overwritten print with a string

Comment: Exit out of the Python interpreter and restart it. Then `print ("Hello world")` will work properly. It looks like you've done something like `print = "Hello world"`, replacing the `print` function with the string.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes i have used. does it create any probs?

Comment: yes friends...i got the error. I have used  print as a variable. I closed and open the editor. now issue resolved. Still dont know why the error occurs

Comment: The print function has to work correctly even if you shadowed it by calling `__builtins__.print("Hello World")`.

Comment: The error occurs because you told Python to bind the name `print` to some string. So when you use the name `print` it thinks you mean to use that string instead of the `print` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use variable names that shadow python built-in functions. In this case you have re-assigned `print` to a string:

```
>>> print("Hello world")
Hello world
>>> print = "s"
>>> print("Hello world")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Run `del print` to restore the functionality of the `print` function:

```
>>> print = "s"
>>> type(print)
<class 'str'>
>>> del print
>>> type(print)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> print("Hello world")
Hello world
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print ("Hello world")
```

works as intended for me, one way to get the

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

is for example with this :

```
print ("Hello world"())
```

You don't have redefined the 'print' function by mystake ?